# Why does the ASA 5512-X not support traffic shaping?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

The cisco documentation claims that the ASA 5512-X does not support traffic shaping because it is a multi processor device. Why is this?

Is shaping just inherently active?

It seems like the shapper is a good feature, i don't understand why it is not available.

To add more details, the shape command is not available under the class default policy, it is located elsewhere? 
Here is what I normally apply

```
class-map RTP-traffic
 match dscp ef 
class-map SIP-traffic
 match dscp af31 

policy-map voice-policy
 class RTP-traffic
  priority
 class SIP-traffic
  priority

policy-map outside-policy
 class class-default
  shape average 5000000
  service-policy voice-policy

service-policy outside-policy interface outside
```

But when I go to apply this i only see

```
ASAX(config-pmap-c)# policy-map outside-policy
ASAX(config-pmap)#  class class-default
ASAX(config-pmap-c)# ?

MPF policy-map class configuration commands:
  exit             Exit from MPF class action configuration mode
  help             Help for MPF policy-map class/match submode commands
  no               Negate or set default values of a command
  police           Rate limit traffic for this class
  priority         Strict scheduling priority for this class
  quit             Exit from MPF class action configuration mode
  set              Set connection values
  user-statistics  configure user statistics for identity firewall
  <cr>
  csc              Content Security and Control service module
  flow-export      Configure filters for NetFlow events
  inspect          Protocol inspection services
  ips              Intrusion prevention services
```

And the shape is not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shaping is not supported at this time on the new hardware. This is a hardware limitation with multi-processor multi-core units, not a software limitation. 
This is not specifically detailed in the document mentioned above. I asked a Cisco product rep and he confirmed that it is not support.

https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2231107

Answer (score 4):

The 5580 and 5585X are multi processor units. The 5512X is not and does support traffic shaping except it does not support it on the Management interface (M0/0).

> Traffic shaping is not supported on multi-processor models, such as
> the ASA 5580 or ASA 5585-X.
>
> ...
>
> (ASA 5512-X through ASA 5555-X) Priority queuing is not supported on
> the Management 0/0 interface.

[Configuring QoS on ASA 8.4](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/conns_qos.html)

Comment: I added some more notes to the question above. When you are under the class-default shape is not available. The firmware is SMP firmware. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Trying to enable shapping via the ASDM also fails. It must be something to do with the SMP. With this model are you able to run the NON SMP firmware, or will it now work ?